# Creating Outlook application from Excel generates type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, type-mismatch

I am trying to create an Outlook email using an Outlook template.

On the `Set obApp = Outlook.Application` line, I am receiving the error:

> Error: 13 Type Mismatch

I seem to be using the same syntax used in other posts on this site on the subject.

I also tried `Set obApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Applciation")` with the same result.

I have OLE Automation, Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Office 16.0 Library, and Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, and visual Basic for Applications all checked in Tools-> References.

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate()
    Dim obApp As Application
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application 'THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("F:\Folder1\Automation\EmailTemplates\TEST TEST.oft")
    NewMail.Display

End Sub
```

Comment: If the code is in Outlook then no need to set application, simply use ‘Application.CreateItem’

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to choose from:

## Option 1: Early Binding

In order to use early binding, you need to set a reference to:

```
Microsoft Outlook ##.# Object Library
```

Which can be done in the VBE > Tools > References. I assume this is the method you are preferring due to the way you have already declared your variables.

The issue in your code using this method is that in the statement `Dim xxxx As Application`, `As Application` is referring to **Excel's Object Model**. You need to specify you are wanting to use Outlook.

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate()

    Dim obApp As New Outlook.Application    '<-- Notice Change
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("F:\Folder1\Automation\EmailTemplates\TEST TEST.oft")
    NewMail.Display

End Sub
```

## Option 2: Late Binding

You will not need to set a reference in this method, but Outlook's types and constants will not be available at compile time. The compiler will obtain these during runtime.

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate()

    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Object

    Set obApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("F:\Folder1\Automation\EmailTemplates\TEST TEST.oft")
    NewMail.Display

End Sub
```

Notice in this method Outlook's objects were declared as type `Object`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in case 1 (early binding) you can use the `New` syntax instead of `GetObject()` - i.e `Set obApp = New Outlook.Application`, which I think feels a bit cleaner

Comment: @Greedo Depends - I wouldn't necessarily want to create a new object if one is already running. Could you imagine running this code 50 times and having 50 instances open? Sure, you could close the application at the end of the routine, but if the object already exists then why not use it? I probably could have added a check to see if `olApp Is Nothing` first and then proceed to create a new object.

Comment: Ah so true, I mistakenly thought you were using `CreateObject()`as in the question. There's no early bound /`New ` style equivalent of `GetObject()` is there?  Something like `Set obApp = Existing Outlook.Application` (which has the minor benefit of being able to dot through the library). And what scope does `GetObject()` look in - same method and publicly declared variables, or somehow global? Like should a parent method be worried about a child hijacking its instance in this way?

Comment: Unfortunately for both early and late binding, there is no equivalent of `As New...` to `GetObject()`. And with _"...hijacking its instance in this way"_: I suppose this ultimately boils down to security. Any piece of malware could supposedly gain access to ActiveX/COM programs this way, which would be why it's important to keep your OS and antivirus software up to date, @Greedo.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not suggesting anything so nefarious. All I'm wondering is whether under normal circumstances, `GetObject` has sight of variables that are not in the method's scope. If __Sub a__ has `Set a = CreateObject("foo.bar")`, can __Sub b__ in a different scope do `Set b = GetObject("foo.bar")` to get `a`'s object, where `Set b = a` would give a _variable not defined_ error because of the difference in scope

Comment: No, you would use `GetObject()` to obtain an object _that is not assigned to a variable in your project_. To pass an object to another routine, you would either have to place an argument in that routine `Sub test(myObj As Object)` or make the object a variable of the module's declarations. @Greedo

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs This worked initially for me (both early and late binding methods), although I just tried running the code without an instance of the Outlook application already open. When doing so, I get a `Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object` prompt on line `Set obApp = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")`.

Comment: @OrangeOwner I just did some testing, and creating the object actually will just use the existing instance anyway, so I removed the `GetObject()` and updated the code. See if that works for you.