# Referencing Outlook library generates "Name of module, project or library already in use"

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-office

In Excel 2016 VBA, I cannot refer to both Office Objects Library and Outlook Objects library.

I need the first one for calling the file picker of Office

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

I need the second to get to the Apointments of Outlook:

```
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myItem = OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

When the MSO 16.0 Office Reference library (in the tools/references list) is selected, I cannot select the 'Outlook 16.0 Object Library' (Excel complains about a conflict).

Is there a way to change these two modules and use their objects (opening a file with msoOfficeLibrary and opening an appointment with Outlook)?

Comment: May be .. [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247312/9808063)

Comment: Thanks for the link...I have tried to suppress the OLE automation reference. In this case,  the references Office and Outlook work, and I can access to both libraries without conflict. For example, I can use the file selector of Office and I can create an Outlook appointment with VBA.  But I worry about suppressing the OLE automation reference: I don't know what will be lacking after this suppression. For example, will I be able to open the date picker of Outlook to chose a date for an appointment ? I will see...

Comment: What particular line of your code does Excel VBA complain about?

Comment: @Dmitry. As I said, the problem is not seen when starting from scratch. It appears in my application specifically and I don't know why. To answer your question : The compilation stops on "Dim oCont As ContactItem" and complains (that is perfectly normal) about an unknown type. So, as usual, I realize that I miss the Outlook reference and try to add it with tools/references menu. And when I check the line "Outlook" , it says something like "Name of module, project or library already in use". And so I cannot load Outlook. The other references I have are VBA, Excel, Forms, Office/

Answer (score 0):

Both references can be freely added to the VBA project. I don't get any issues when dealing with these objects in the code. Most probably you need to correct object declarations - use fully-qualified names and use the option strict on.

Comment: you are certainly right as I have also an example that is working with these two references. I was suspecting maybe the OLE automation reference (I had it alseo) but it works also. It is just a specific application I work on that doesn't accept to load the Outlook reference and I cannot figure out whiy so far.

Comment: Most probably you can't reference two Application classes, you need to introduce an alias for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I named my VBA module 'Outlook'.

That was a bad choice. It kept VBA from loading the "Microsoft Outlook 16.0" Object Library.